# Efficiency executing query multiple times inside a function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, function, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with about 40 columns. I saved all headers inside one table.
I use a function, inside a sp that generates a report, to get all the headers (dynamic sql).

The function contains a query which queries the headertable with the parameters. This functions executes 40 times, so the query runs 40 times.

Instead of running the query inside the function 40 times is there a solution to do it more efficiently?

EDIT: Changed story a little, maybe more clear now

Comment: It's still a bit unclear what you are trying to do.  Also the code example doesn't look quite right (mismatched quotes, etc.).

Comment: @GordonLinoff They are not

Answer (score 0):

If only the header would defer i would create different views and query the views which would call a table function (you would need to rewrite your report to a table function) or i would write the stored proc to a table.

Comment: That would be one solution :).